# How to append 2 div to 1 div with both this 2 child div side by side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below are my div:

```
<div id="10" class="latestblock">
    <img>
    <span>Abc</span>
</div>

<div id="11" class="latestblock">
    <img>
    <span>pqr</span>
</div>

function AppendDiv(10,11)
{
var eFrom = $('#' + 10);
var toDiv = $('#' + 11);
var htmldiv = eFrom.toString() + toDiv.toString();
  <!--$("#large").html
                (
                    htmldiv
                ).center().fadeIn("slow");--> Not working
}
```

Now i want to append both this div to this below div:

```
<div id="large"></div>
```

I want this div like this:

[image]

My generated output html should be like this:

```
<div id="large">
    <div id="10" class="latestblock">
        <img>
        <span>Abc</span>
    </div>

    <div id="11" class="latestblock">
        <img>
        <span>pqr</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to do this??

Comment: `function AppendDiv(10,11)` is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.append()`

```
$("#large").append(eFrom.fadeOut(0), toDiv.fadeOut(0)).find("div").fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: @Learning Yes, `js` at post should return expected results.

Comment: @Learning _":oops sorry i think i havent properly posted my question but now can you edit your ans to reflect this"_ Though requirement does not appear at OP, to display `div` child elements of `#large` side-by-side you can use `css` `#large > div {
  display:inline-block !important;
}` jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1p23rhbv/1/

Comment: @Learning Using `.add()`, substituting `.fadeTo()` for `.fadeIn()`, `.fadeOut()` jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1p23rhbv/2/

Comment: Can you explain me little bit what wrong with my code because i am poor with jquery and havent work much with it so

Comment: @Learning _"Can you explain me little bit what wrong with my code"_ `jQuery().toString()` returns `"[object Object]"` , not `DOM` element. You can use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append) _"DOM element, array of elements, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements."_ to append existing element to different parent element within `document`

Comment: But I have tried like this too:eFrom + toDiv without using tostring but still I was getting [object object]

Comment: @Learning `+` operator concatenates strings or casts to string. You can use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add) _"Create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements."_ to add elements to an existing jQuery selector, see jsfiddle at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976606/how-to-append-2-div-to-1-div-with-both-this-2-child-div-side-by-side/36976677#comment61509681_36976677 @Rayon pointed out numbers passed as variable names at `AppendDiv` function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110800/discussion-between-learning-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 3):

`10` and `11` can not be argument names(Your argument names can not be values but variables and variables can not start with `Numbers`). Use `outerHTML` to grab `Markup` of the `selected elements`. Make the elements `.hide()` to be `fadeIn()`

```js
function AppendDiv(one, two) {
  var eFrom = $('#' + one);
  var toDiv = $('#' + two);
  var htmldiv = eFrom[0].outerHTML + toDiv[0].outerHTML;
  $("#large").html(htmldiv).hide().fadeIn("slow");
}


AppendDiv('10', '11');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="10" class="latestblock">
  <img>
  <span>Abc</span>
</div>

<div id="11" class="latestblock">
  <img>
  <span>pqr</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="large"></div>
```

**Note:** As pointed out by [*guest271314*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314), You will be having duplicate `id` elements in the DOM which is not recommended.

Comment: Would `.html()`  only return `.innerHTML` of elements, not including `<div>` parent element?

Comment: @Rayon Updated post creates duplicate `id`'s in `document`?

Comment: @guest271314, This is how OP wants it.. The only thing I could do it to highlight it...

Comment: @Rayon No, OP wants elements appended to new element. Duplicate `id` in `document` is invalid `html`

Comment: But i want to display it side by side with some distance

Comment: @Rayon `.append()` or `.appendTo()` should return expected results

Comment: @Learning _"But i want to display it side by side with some distance"_ does not appear at original Question?

Comment: @guest271314:please see my posted image

Comment: @Learning The posted image does not actually describe expected result. Requirement as described at original Question appears to be _"Now i want to append both this div to this below div:"_ , _"My generated output html should be like this:"_

Comment: @guest271314:oops sorry i think i havent properly posted my question but now can you edit your ans to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

Make it more easier. Just define html() of both div in a variable and then append it in `#large` div.

```
var div1 = $('#10')[0].outerHTML;
var div2 = $('#11')[0].outerHTML;

$('#large').append(div1 + div2);
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/86zx3b5m/2/

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Would updated post create duplicate `id`'s in `document`?

Comment: ofcourse...because these are duplicates so duplicate id will be there and may create problem. @Learning if possible you can update the id's when appending or use class